# How to schedule function calls execution in a queue?

Tags: java

I have an interface

```
interface Methods {
    void MethodX(int X);
    void MethodY(int Y);
    // ...
}
```

Interface implementation has to schedule calls to interface methods in a blocking queue (so that calls are executed sequentially). Is there any simple way to do that like?

```
Something.post(...);
```

Where ... is some wrapper call around MethodZ.

Calls to interface are non-blocking (it is an AIDL interface), but internally each next call should be executed not before the previous one finishes.

Comment: I bet, you can do it in Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like:

```
class MethodZExecutor implements Callable<Void> {

  private final Methods method;
  private int argument;

  public MethodZExecutor(Methods method, int argument) {
    this.method = method;
    this.argument = argument;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() {
    method.MethodZ(argument);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then create your blocking queue to hold `Callable` objects. Dequeue items from this queue and call `call()` on them.

Note: this could all happen using anonymous inner classes, depending upon your use case:

```
someQueue.post(new Callable<Void>() {
  @Override
  public Void call() {
    foo.MethodZ(someArgument);
    return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put function objects into queue and directly call them. The only limitation is passing data to functions.

You can check function objects in Java from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Java). Another option is to use lambda expressions to create anonymous class objects with the function you want to call in it and push this object into queue. Check lambda expressions at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Note that lambda expressions are a feature of Java 8, which is not currently released. (Not complaining, just adding that info as an FYI).